# When does the Mahabharata indicate the onset of widespread Varna Sankarya (i.e., inter-caste marriages) in society?

Tags: mahabharata, history, marriage, varna

In a discussion with Nahusha, Yudhisthira states

> 'In human society, O mighty and highly intelligent serpent, it is
> difficult to ascertain one's caste, **because of promiscuous
> intercourse among the four orders**. This is my opinion. **Men
> belonging to all orders (promiscuously) beget offspring upon women of
> all the orders. And of men, speech, sexual intercourse, birth and
> death are common.** And to this the Rishis have borne testimony by
> using as the beginning of a sacrifice such expressions as--of what
> caste so ever we may be, we celebrate the sacrifice. Therefore, those
> that are wise have asserted that character is the chief essential
> requisite. The natal ceremony of a person is performed before division
> of the umbilical cord. His mother then acts as its Savitri and his
> father officiates as priest. He is considered as a Sudra as long as he
> is not initiated in the Vedas. Doubts having arisen on this point, O
> prince; of serpents, Swayambhuba Manu has declared, that the mixed
> castes are to be regarded as better than the (other) classes, if
> having gone through the ceremonies of purification, the latter do not
> conform to the rules of good conduct, O excellent snake! Whosoever now
> conforms to the rules of pure and virtuous conduct, him have I, ere
> now, designated as a Brahmana.'
>
> [[Section 179, Tirtha-yatra Parva, Vana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03179.htm)

This exchange takes place just before the Kurukshetra War, during the transitional period from Dwapara Yuga to Kali Yuga. It strongly implies that there was not strict adherence to the Varna system during this time, leading to a widespread phenomenon of Varna Sankarya, or the mixing of castes.

My intention is not to explore the onset of Varna Sankarya within a small societal segment, such as a Kuru family, but rather, to understand when this began to happen within society at large during the Dwapara Yuga. Are there passages in the Mahabharata that directly or indirectly pinpoint a specific time when Varna Sankarya became a prevalent trend across society?

Comment: Vyasadeva himself was born out of an intercaste union. So was Parashurama & his father Jamadagni. Agastya married Lopamudra, who was born in a kshatriya family. Similarly Cyavana married the kshatriyā Sukanya. So the phenomenon of intercaste marriage was already widespread by the time Yudhisthira came.

Comment: Padma Purana says that there was a temporary disturbance in the cosmos due to Lakshmi abandoning Svarga by the curse of Durvasa which manifested in the form of deviation from orthodoxy, which resulted in the acceptance of anuloma marriage by the rishis.

Comment: "Varna Samkara" existed all the way back in Indus Valley Civilization "Indus Valley Civilization had been a combination of diverse racial elements. Certain anthropological investigations and examinations of the human remains show that four racial types existed in this civilization namely Pro-Australiod,Mediterranean. Alpinoid and the Mongoloid".